# How to make sharepoint o365 custom list columns searchable

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-integration

We are trying to make already existed list column to searchable.It is a choice field with active and archive data. We need to get archive data in search result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the "Allow items from this list to appear in search result" by navigating to List setting -> Advance setting then enable the below mentioned option and if already that options is enabled then click "Reindex List", search will re-index those item and make it available for search on next crawl.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much now i'm able to get correct results

Answer (score 2):

In order to surface the choice field in SharePoint search you will have to map the crawled property to a managed property as per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/crawled-and-managed-properties-overview

Answer (score 0):

All of the text in the column is indexed by default. To be able to search based on a property (Status=Active, Price>100, etc.) see Kasper Bo Larsen's answer.